# Should I still use many-to-many db structure if I only have a few-to-many?

Tags: php, mysql, html, webforms

I'm new to web development and could really use some advice. Thank you all in advance!

I have a form where I ask users to rate their experience in several areas (Mental, Physical, Fun) from 1 - 10. There are about 10 areas in all. Is it worth it to make a table of areas and a intersection table with areaID and userID? In this case, wouldn't it be easier to just create one table with 11 columns (one for each area plus a userID)?

I understand that a table of 'areas' with a key of areaID would be the most robust, and allow me to later add more areas but I really don't see myself doing that. Also, as I only expect <1000 users, would adding another column to a MySQL db be a lot of work?

Finally, what is the cutoff point where I actually should use a many-to-many structure? Later in the form I have users rate ~30 fields from 1 - 4. Should I use the two table system there?

Thanks again!

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that the number of areas will _never_ change? Are you certain that you _can_ be certain about that? As an aside, the definition of "many" in "many-to-many" is literally "more than one."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It'd be better to use the separate child table. The SQL overhead for a join is minimal, and you get total flexibility in how many/few entries you want to allow, without ever having to change the database structure.

It may only be 10 areas now, but PHBs are notorious for changing their minds about something that was "bedrock" on the hour before launch.

Comment: Sigh . . . OK. Thank you for taking the time to advice a FNG

Comment: Then what is a good way of storing those values in the intersection table? Do I need to compare each of the area names to rows in the area's table, find the appropriate areaID, and then add that to the intersection table? Is there any better way?

Answer (score 4):

I would *always* model a many-to-many relationship with a proper intersection table because you can *never* predict what the future will bring.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you want to count the number of areas per user.  How would you do that if you use a single table with 11 columns?

Implement this with the intersection table.  You will be glad you did.

Answer (score 1):

Both makes sense, but I would choose the many-to-many approach as you can then specify in the areas table the name of each area (and maybe add some comments what 1 or 10 for that specific area means, etc..)

Answer (score 0):

There's no wrong answer to this, but consider this: are you sure that that number will remain fixed at ten?

Personally, I would still use the many-to-many relationship. It's the more elegant solution, and, in my mind, better. However, doing a job well is often a waste of time.

Comment: It's a waste of time if you want to put together a quick prototype or the technical debt won't bite you in the butt before you can palm it off to someone else.

Comment: Doing a job well may not always be fully appreciated later, but you can certainly waste more time redesigning if you didn't do the job well/flexibly up front.

Comment: Sometimes, programming consists of scripts that you use once and then throw away. I'm a huge believer in paradigms that encourage flexibility like OOP, but three lines of chalked Perl that you'll use once or twice is better than eighty lines of elegant Java for the same purpose.

Comment: Oh, absolutely. I didn't mean to imply that one should _always_ do it the "long" way. My emphasis was on that largely because the asker's question seemed like a scenario when the "long" way would be best, and because you _could_ waste much more time redesigning something that should have been more flexible than you would when you design something to be more flexible than necessary.